# How to specify column data types when writing Spark Dataframe to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark

I am writing a Spark dataframe to SQL Server as can be seen by the following code extract.

```
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};database={2}".format(jdbcHostname,jdbcPort,jdbcDatabase)
mydf = spark.sql(f"SELECT * FROM {source['db']}.{source['table']}")
mydf.write\
  .format("jdbc")\
  .mode("overwrite")\
  .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")\
  .option("url", url)\
  .option("dbtable", f"{destination['db']}.dbo.{destination['table']}")\
  .option("user", properties['user'])\
  .option("password", properties['password'])\
  .option("batchSize", 50000)\
  .save()
```

However, string fields are stored as nvarchar by default whereas I would like to specify a varchar value for them. Performing casts on the dataframe beforehand to convert column datatypes did not help.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: When creating a destination table you'd use the `createTableColumnTypes` option. When using an existing table it's up to Spark to transform the data types. Ref: [JDBC to Other Databases](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases)

Answer (score 1):

You should implement JdbcDialect and register it.

> https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/jdbc/JdbcDialect.html

1. Override method getJDBCType() and provide types you want.

   ```
   public CustomDialect extends JdbcDialect {

    @Override
    public boolean canHandle(String url) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Option<JdbcType> getJDBCType(DataType dt) {
        if (dt.equals(DataTypes.StringType)) {
            return new Some<>(new JdbcType("VARCHAR(1000)", Types.VARCHAR));
        }
        return super.getJDBCType(dt);
    }

    @Override
    public String quoteIdentifier(String colName) {
        return colName;
    }
   ```

   }
2. Register dialect

> JdbcDialects.registerDialect( new CustomDialect());